# C# Windows registry GetValue Error

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I have a program which outputs the various registry values from "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\LastVisitedMRU".

However the program outputs an error on Cannot implicity convert type'object' to 'string' at the s variable at the GetValue portion or the program! And the program outputs an error of "Cannot access a closed registry key too".

Can someone please give advise on the codes? Thanks!

The Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace RegKeys
{
class ConsoleApplication1
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser;

            rk = rk.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\LastVisitedMRU", false);
            PrintKeys(rk);
        }

        catch (Exception MyError)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error has occurred: " + MyError.Message);
        }
    }

    static void PrintKeys(RegistryKey rk)
    {
        if (rk == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No specified registry key!");
            return;
        }

        String[] names = rk.GetValueNames();

        Console.WriteLine("Subkeys of " + rk.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------");

        foreach (String s in names)
        {
            try
            {
                if (s == "MRUList")
                {
                    continue;
                }

                else
                {
                    String val = rk.GetValue(s);
                    Console.WriteLine(s + " Contains the value of : " + val);
                }

                rk.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception MyError)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error has occurred: " + MyError.Message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------");
            rk.Close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As well as Matti's advice, it's not clear why you're looking through *all* the subvalues. Why not just get the one you want? Something like this:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey
               (@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\" + 
                @"Explorer\ComDlg32\LastVisitedMRU", false))
        {
            string value = (string) key.GetValue("MRUList");
            Console.WriteLine(value);            
        }
    }
}
```

(Note the using statement to make sure you always close the registry key.)

You might *also* want to put in some tests to make sure the key and value exist, of course.

Comment: The value returned is a REG_BINARY type. I have managed to get the binary values but can you advise on how to convert binary to string?

Answer (score 3):

Here's some advice on the codes:

GetValue returns an `object`, not a `string`. You need to either cast it to string, or call `ToString` on it (always use the former if you know it's actually a string).

Comment: The value type of the GetValue is a binary value of REG_Binary. Do you know how to convert or store those variables?

Comment: @JavaNoob: I'd imagine that their value would be an array of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the expected result is string, just typecast it.

```
String val = (String) rk.GetValue(s);
//or
String val = rk.GetValue(s) as String;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe GetValue is expecting a lowercase 's' string, which is a primitive, as opposed to an uppercase 'S' String which is an object.  Try this:

```
String val = rk.GetValue(s.toString());
```

Or in general replace your usage of 'string' with 'String' except where 'String' is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Convert.ToString()` method to convert the `object` to string. You can also use `.ToString()` but it may result in a null reference exception if the key does not exist.

Secondly, on the exception you get with the closed key. Change your `for each` loop and move the rk.Close() call outside the loop.

```
    foreach (String s in names)
    {
        try
        {
            if (s == "MRUList")
            {
                continue;
            }

            else
            {
                String val = rk.GetValue(s);
                Console.WriteLine(s + " Contains the value of : " + val);
            }


        }

        catch (Exception MyError)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error has occurred: " + MyError.Message);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------");

    }
    rk.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a struct and trying to do this. I kept getting objects returned when I wanted strings and when I did .ToString() the whole program just froze up. I realized that the properties I wanted to retrieve are also fields. It took me all day to figure it out:

```
string value = myObjectInstance.GetType().
   GetField("myFieldName").GetValue(newEntry) as string;
```

That worked perfectly for me.